# Bind DispatcherTimer Interval with Slider Value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, slider, dispatchertimer

I was wondering if it is possible to bind `Slider`'s `Value` to `DispatcherTimer`'s `Interval`? I know I can subscribe for `ValueChanged` event and then just simply do `timer.Interval = new TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(slider.Value)`, but is it possible to achieve the same effect using just `Binding` mechanism? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need a `IValueConverter` in between binding because Interval is if type TimeSpan and Value is of type double. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I know about converters, but I'm having trouble strictly with binding these values. `Interval` has no `DependencyProperty`, but there has to be a way to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't data bind between a `DispatcherTimer.Interval` property and a `Slider.Value` property directly. What you *can* do is to declare a property that you can data bind to the `Slider.Value` property and in the `setter`, set your `DispatcherTimer.Interval` property. Try something like this::

```
public double Milliseconds
{
    get { return milliseconds; }
    set
    {
        milliseconds = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Milliseconds");
        yourTimer.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((int)milliseconds);
    }
}
```

...

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Milliseconds}" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you @Sheridan for your response. It's almost what I was looking for, but I guess I'm missing something. When I use `NotifyPropertyChanged("Milliseconds");` I keep getting an error `"The name does not exist in current context"`. I checked and this function is defined for `DataGrid`. What should I use instead? Or mabe defining a separate class with `DispatcherTimer` inside that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` will be the answer?

Comment: I assumed that you were implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class (like you should be), but if not, just omit that line.

Comment: I should have posted some code. I currently have my `DispatcherTimer` in my `MainWindow` class. So just to be sure, Is it better to create some `TimerHelper` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use it's instance instead of `DispatcherTimer` in `MainWindow`?

Comment: It is customary to define a class that contains *all data properties and functionality* that is required by the `Window` and set an instance of that as the `Window.DataContext`. Your `Milliseconds` property and timer should go in there.